# MicrosoftGraph on Enterprise Exchange Server

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Can the MicrosoftGraph API, specifically the WebHooks, be used for accounts on an enterprise / on-premise Exchange server as opposed to Office 365.
All the documentation I have seen for setting up the app required for OAuth authentication use Azure.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, the question linked is bound to Office356 API, whereas this question revolves around graph.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ["hybrid deployment"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support) model currently in preview that allows you to traverse both on-prem and online mailboxes using Microsoft Graph. You can read about the infrastructure requirements at [On-Premises Architectural Requirements for the REST API](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/).

One note on authentication, Microsoft Graph uses OAUTH tokens to handle authentication. These tokens are issued by Azure AD but this does not mean that your entire infrastructure needs to be hosted on Azure, only that your AD be synced with an Azure AD instance using [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect). Depending on the size of the organization you may even be able to use the [Free trier of Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/). I highly recommend taking a look into this configuration as Azure AD is quickly becoming an assumed prerequisite for new APIs and services.